How to access multiple versions of oracle
My project is springboot based.
I'm using maven and java 1.8 .
This project is an application that requires access to multiple DBs.
The problem is that the versions of oracle among multiple DBs are different.
Example: oracle 9i, oracle 11g, 12c
Is it possible to branch by oracle version using datasource? Can you give me some help or feedback?
I accessed it with ojdbc7, which is currently in use, but there was still an error. It accepts string types, abnormal requests, and result values.
